# Passing a query parameter from an AJAX get call to an express route

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I'm playing around with a twitter API wrapper for Node right now and am trying to figure out how to pass a query parameter from an HTML form to an AJAX get request and have that parameter then passed into my Express route, rather than just having the form action go directly to the route.

Here's my HTML code

```
  <form id="searchTerm">
    Keyword:<input id="keyword" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Keyword">
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

My client-side Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchTerm').on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data: q,
      url: '/search/tweets/term',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

And then my Node.JS route:

```
// Search by keywords or phrases
app.get('/search/tweets/term', function(req, res) {
  var q = req.query.q;

// Accesses the Twitter API and pulls back the respective tweets
  client.get('search/tweets', {q: q, count: 100, lang: 'en', exclude: 'retweets'}, function(error, tweets, response) {
    if(!error) {
      res.send(tweets);
    } else {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send(error.stack);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm getting a "Query Missing Parameters" error message in my terminal whenever I input a value into the form, however. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

Got it working via the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchTerm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var q = $('#keyword').val();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data: {q: q},
      url: '/search/tweets/term',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    })
  })
})
```

However, since I'm implementing e.preventDefault(), I'm losing the query parameters within my URL. Since I want to give users the ability to share URL's to specific keywords, is there any way to be able to keep these parameters intact in the URL while still getting the JSON sent client side? Or will have to just manipulate the JSON on the server side and have the data be rendered in via a template engine?

Comment: `data: q,` where did you define `q`?

Comment: data: "q" quots?

Comment: Prevent the form submit. Because if you don't your ajax is fetching the result, but the web page has navigated to the next page...

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari - Even if I add:

`var q = $('#keyword').val()`

to the scope outside of the ajax call, I still receive the error

@deostroll Tried that as well and it still seemed to be giving me the same error. Really scratching my head at this one

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchTerm').on('submit', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      data: q,
      url: '/search/tweets/term?q=',
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: any explanation from your 'Try this' ? for example, why your code is working and why OP code is not working.

Comment: He is using var q = req.query.q on the node parameter which requires the q parameter to get the value.